# Difference between change (n) and coins (n)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

I am interested in any differences between the two nouns *change* and *coins* in actual usage. These nouns have different but similar meanings. I am only interested in the difference of the meaning of:

- change (*n*):

> money in the form of coins

- coins (*n)*:

> small, flat, and usually round pieces of metal issued by a government
>   as money

*Source: Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary*

[image]

The difference between these two definitions is not always clear for me. Are there slight differences or are these two terms 100% interchangeable?

What is the difference between:

1. a) I've got a $10 bill and about $3 in change.
   b) I've got a $10 bill and about $3 in coins.
2. a) a pocketful of loose change
   b) a pocketful of loose coins
3. a) The beggar asked us if we had any spare change. [=a small amount of money that we did not need]
   b) The beggar asked us if we had spare coins. [=a small amount of money that we did not need]
4. a) Have you got any change for this note?
   b) Have you got coins for this note?
5. a) I had no change for the parking meter so I didn't pay. 
   b) I had no coins for the parking meter so I didn't pay.
6. a) gold/silver/copper coins 
   b) gold/silver/copper change
7. a) I have a dollar in coins.
   b) I have a dollar in change.
8. a) He collects coins from around the world.
   b) He collects change from around the world.

Comment: Usage, my good man, usage. The longer you read or hear English, the more likely you will be able to choose the word that a native English speaker would use. Sometimes they are interchangeable, sometimes not.

Comment: Please, please, please, use **more than one dictionary.**

Answer (score 1):

The definition of [*change*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/change) that was provided is incomplete:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 a** : money in small denominations received in exchange for an equivalent sum in larger denominations
>   **2 b** : money returned when a payment exceeds the amount due
>   // a cashier quick at making *change*
>   **2 c** : coins especially of low denominations
>   // a pocketful of *change*

Only sense **2 c** was included as the definition in the question.

---

*Coins* represent money, and they can always be considered change in the *one* sense of their definition (**2 c** above), but in the other two senses of the word, *coins* are not always what's returned.

In other words, *change* (in the other senses of the word) can be either bills *or* coins:

> She was given small bills and coins in change.

So, in some cases, the words can be used interchangeably—but not in all cases. It depends on the context.

Comment: True, change is not always given in coins, but is may be worthwhile to add that coins are not always change (either actual or potential). In 'he owns a collection of valuable gold coins', one couldn't use *change* instead of *coins*.

Comment: To all: Please do not discuss @Jason Bassford's 2 a and 2 b here. I only want to discuss "change def. 2 c" with "coin".

Comment: @Wogehu A problem is that in examples like your example 3a, the sense of 'change' used is indeterminate. Even the M-W definitions are inadequately explained; 'any spare change' '[= a small amount of money that we did not need]' can of course include low-denomination bills.  That said, there is an implication when the 'coins' (or indeed any other related) subsense of 'change' is intended/used that the coins mentioned are associated with pockets / gifts to tramps / coin drawers / transactions / minor sums. Numismatists don't 'collect change', and we speak only of gold, silver and copper 'coins'.

Comment: @Wogehu The problem is that in your question, only sentences 6 and 8 are (without being contrived) unambiguously meant in the third Merriam-Webster sense. All of the other sentences are open to interpretation.

Comment: If there are space for interpretation, please interprete all example sentences as M-W definition 2 c. I have the most of this example sentences from "Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary". "Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary" provides example sentences to each definition. I have not collected any example sentences from definition 2 a and 2 b. I thought, it would be good as basis for discussion to have some examples, because this way, it would be clearer what exactly my question is. I can't make up my own sentences.

Comment: I disagree that coins can always be considered change (2c). Change is inherently _low-denomination_, which coins aren’t necessarily. Granted, most currencies nowadays use notes/bills for higher denominations, but that wasn’t always the case. In late Roman times, for example, the denarius coin was worth something like the equivalent of £15–20, which I wouldn’t call _change_ (I’m not posh or rich enough for that).